# How to get San Francisco font into Xcode?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, xcode7

I just download and installed the SF fonts.  I see them in Sketch and the Font Book but not Xcode (Interface Builder).  I've restarted Xcode but the SF or San Francisco fonts still do not show up in the text tool.

Does anyone know if something special is required to get them working in Xcode?

OS X 10.11.1
Xcode 7.1.1

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is to add your (.ttf) file to resources. You can drag and drop it and then a dialogue box will appear after that check the checkbox for your application and you should be set. Then add the font to Targets >> Build Phase >> Copy Bundle Resources and thats it.