# Default font(system font) for Xcode 7.3.1 is San Francisco font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I need to use San Francisco font in my app. But I'm not sure if the default font (system font) in my current Xcode is SF font. My app is supporting iOS 7 and above and I need all OS version to use SF font.

1. So, I want to know how can I do this?
2. Is the default system font in 7.3.1 using SF font? I've checked in Font Book app but I didn't see SF font.
3. Do I need to install it to use it? (like in this question: [How to get San Francisco font into Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109428/how-to-get-san-francisco-font-into-xcode))

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 with OS 10.11.2. The font is set in Storyboard, not progamatically.

Answer (score 3):

**Helvetica Neue** was the default font for iOS 8 and prior. Apple has changed its default font from iOS 9 to **San Francisco**.

1) For your app If you want consistent font for all iOS versions then you have to explicitly set the San Francisco font via Storyboard or code.

2) iOS default font is based on iOS version not Xcode version. So, If you want SF fonts for iOS then then you have to install that font. Also If you want to make available that font in storyboard then you have to add that font in Apple Font Book app by double clicking on font file. *(**Note:** Any custom font set by storyboard was not added in App then it will use the default font)*

3) YES

Comment: i've seen this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345768/can-we-user-san-francisco-font-for-ios-8-applications-if-yes-best-way-to-user?rq=1

will my app be rejected if I use the font on iOS 8?